# Word for protective disc between screw/bolt and material?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to order a product online, but can't seem to find any. So I have a feeling that there might be a word that I am missing.

What I am looking for is the name of the often round disc, used as an area enlargener between a screw or a bolt, and the material it is inserted into.

More specifically, I am looking for the round metal variant, 50mm diameter, and 10mm thickness, if that matters for the name.

Searching for metal discs, even with the proper dimensions, I can only find grinding and cutting discs, or other kinds of tools.

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about [one of these](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/2484595/?grossPrice=Y&cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_UK_EN_Fasteners_And_Fixings-_-Nuts_And_Washers%7CPlain_Washers-_-PRODUCT+GROUP&matchtype=&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuP7UBRDiARIsAFpxiRJfTz42eVYBh7FXpFQABRFfVgtemoBekc0gbxeBOBNXUFMhvOm61QsaAr7MEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) then I have never used anything but ***washer***. Though where the word comes from is a mystery. The OED says it is of "doubtful origin", though they do have examples of its use since the fourteenth century.

> 1a. A perforated annular disc or flattened ring of metal, leather, or
>   other material placed between two surfaces subject to rotative
>   friction, to relieve friction and prevent lateral motion and
>   unsteadiness.
>
> 1346   Accts. Exchequer King's Remembrancer 470/17 m. 2   De..v
>   Cheynes pro barr[a] continentibus L. Linches, v. paribus tenellarum,
>   ij. Whashers [etc.].
>
> 1544   in Lett. & Papers Henry VIII XIX. i. 148   Spare wheles for
>   small ordynaunce 12 pair, lynce~pynnes, wasshers, [etc.].
>
> 1611   J. Florio Queen Anna's New World of Words   Cérchio di ferro,
>   an iron hoope, amongst gunners called a washer, which serues to keepe
>   the iron pin at the end of the axeltree from wearing the naue.
>
> 1682   in Early Rec. Town of Providence (Rhode Island) (1894) VI. 93
>   Jn ye Parlor 3 Cart boxes, i lince pinn & a washer 00–01–00.
>
> 1704   Dict. Rusticum at Cart   The Washers, being the Rings on the
>   ends of the Axle-tree.
>
> 1705   tr. G. Guillet de Saint-Georges Gentleman's Dict. ii. at Nave
>   It has likewise in each end of the hole, through which the end of the
>   Axletree goes, a ring of iron called the wisher, which saves the hole
>   of the nave from wearing too big.
>
> 1795   Herschel in Philos. Trans. (Royal Soc.) 85 371   It is keyed
>   fast at C; with proper washers between the joints to allow of a very
>   smooth motion.
>
> 1805   R. W. Dickson Pract. Agric. I. Plate xii   Every tooth screws
>   through a double frame separated by iron washers for greater
>   steadiness.
>
> 1847   R. Brandon & J. A. Brandon Anal. Gothick Archit. I. 102   The
>   closing ring or door latch..[consists of] the flat plate or washer,
>   fixed to the outer surface of the door; the handle or ring; and the
>   spindle.
>
> 1872   O. W. Holmes Poet at Breakfast-table i   A washer..makes a
>   loose screw fit.
>
> 1876   R. D. Blackmore Cripps xxvi   The vast diversity of wheels, as
>   well as their many caprices of wagging, according to the state of
>   their washers.

Comment: Got them in the mail today. They were called "repair washers". Thanks a lot.